# Run Docker image on a different host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-mac

Is it possible to run docker image on **other host than localhost**?

Ports `80` and `443` are always occupied by other applications, so I was wondering if it's possible to run it on, e.g. `192.168.0.100`, and then set up the `/etc/hosts` file to assign a name for that IP address.

I was trying to set up `extra_hosts` option, but I'm not sure if it's meant for that. Either way, I did not succeed with setting it up as there was some issue with `Value should be a mapping, not an array`.

I guess it's worth mentioning that I'm on macOS using `docker-compose` to run everything. Thank you in advance.

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "2"

services:
  php:
    build: ./php
    volumes:
      - ../develog.org:/usr/share/nginx/html
  depends_on:
    - memcached

nginx:
  build: ./nginx
  ports:
    - 4001:80
    - 4002:443
  volumes_from:
    - php:ro
  depends_on:
    - php

memcached:
    image: memcached:alpine

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.1.0.0/16
```

nginx configuration

```
map $scheme $ssl_request {
  https   "https";
}
server {
  # support http and ipv6
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

  # support https and ipv6
  listen 443 default_server ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on default_server ssl;

  # path to web directory
  root /web/;
  index index.html index.htm;

  # domain or subdomain
  server_name localhost;

  include self-signed.conf;
  include ssl-params.conf;
}
```

Comment: You can specify the remote port in docker compose
```ports:
     - "8983:8983"```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a different port when running your image? (unless you *have* to use port 80/443)

So, for example, if you are running a webserver image like Apache httpd, which normally runs on port 80 use:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80/tcp httpd
```

Then you can just use port 8080 on localhost.

For docker-compose add a ports section to the docker-compose.yaml file. E.g.

```
image: <image>
ports:
- "8080:80"
```

The actual ports/image would depend on which image you are using.

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports for details.

Comment: I'm doing it like this right now, but I do have some errors while dealing with 443, as when I'm using custom port for HTTPS, e.g. `4400`, with certificate generated for `localhost, 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0` I always end up with `403 Forbidden` after visiting `https://localhost:4400/`. That's why I'm wondering if it's not a better idea to use defaults but on other host

Comment: might be useful to post your docker-compose.yaml

Comment: Done. I'm new to nginx, so I posted the configuration for that one, too. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: The docs all use quotes around the ports so try that first. But I think your issue is with nginx as you would get a connection refused error if the ports were not working as opposed to "403 forbidden"